# How should I handle a persistently emailing customer who I suspect may be mentally unwell?

Tags: customer-service

I have a customer that sends me pages upon pages about how my product is worthless and I charge too much money for it. The customer initially misunderstood the product's features and now can't stop terrorizing me about how it's worth a fourth of the advertised price.

The "novels" I receive on a daily basis remind me of people in documentaries of madhouses - long sentences without breaks (or fullstops in that regard), no clear train of thought, random chunks of information repeating itself in different phrases all over the place. Now that I think of it, it's a bit how you'd imagine a robot to send you letters. But I'm confident it's not a robot.

The letters simply won't stop and I am absolutely amazed by how much effort this person seems to put in these emails. The problem is that they aren't helpful. I of course can't offer a product for less than what it actually costs to make and I disagree with their suggestions.

Since I've explained these two factors to them numerous times, I suppose this person is either a child or an adult with psychological deficits. I am very confident it's not a child because the writing style doesn't fit there.

To avoid unnecessary trouble I would've loved to just stop this conversation but I am legally bound to replying each email. My response is always something like

> We cannot change the price for the reasons mentioned previously - we don't be able to accommodate this request. If there is anything else you haven't mentioned that we can do for you please let us know.

But they keep the emails coming, repeating the same demands in different variations.

I suppose this is a mentally ill person and I'm unsure if they get the help they need. I have previously had a person sending me unsolicited images all day (since my company email is public) and after about 3 months, this person accidentally included a conversation with him and his friend. This made it possible for me to get in touch with his friend to find out that the "spammer" is a veteran with PTSD who slowly lost his mind due to a bad choice of medications. His friend somehow managed to get my email out of the veteran's system and the emails have stopped. This is probably why I am so firm on the mentally-ill guess, the writing style is similar (but not same, they are different people for sure).

For context: The product is not a $50k car or something that would put you into debt, it costs about $5 with a free return policy. They haven't made use of the return offer, but I'm sure this isn't about the money.

Of course I cannot ask them "Are you out of your mind, do you need help?". Mentally ill people, just like mature, accountable people could be rightfully equally offended by this. How can I go ahead here? Is there another way to ask them about their situation? Should I simply set up an auto responder responding with the same message every time? I really don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Why are you "legally bound" to reply to each email?

Comment: I offer a product for a contractor who requires me to do just that. It's part of the deal and the contractor is too big to even consider making an exception

Comment: Regarding the person sending you the emails, sounds like you already know the answer. Would your employer want to work with such a person anyway? I think it's safe to send them to the spam folder.

Comment: Do you have an agreement with the contractor about how quickly you have to reply?

Comment: Surely your contractor has some sort of policy for frivolous / vexatious correspondence, even if it's not written in to your contract? Your first point of contact there must see that it hurts you, and by implication them, to not shut this sort of behaviour down at the first reasonable opportunity.

Comment: Slightly offtopic... *"people in documentaries of madhouses - long sentences without breaks (or fullstops in that regard), no clear train of thought, random chunks of information repeating itself in different phrases all over the place."* - Look at any social media to see that unfortunately in evolution of societies this style of communication seems to become more and more popular for people even outside of madhouses.

Answer (score 10):

> How can I go ahead here? Is there another way to ask them about their situation? Should I simply set up an auto responder responding with the same message every time?

In **no** way do I suggest you even hint to your customer or indirectly ask if they are mentally ill or not.

Surely there are crazy/intense folk out there, but there is no way to ask "are you mad" to someone in a way that will turn out well.

If you are unsure on how to proceed with this recurrent situation, **call your manager, explain to them about the situation, and ask what you can do about it.**

In the meantime, it seems that you have been doing the professional thing to not take it the wrong way and reply back politely.

Answer (score 4):

You can set up Outlook to have rules to auto-reply with the same reply you have.  You can have it set up to reply periodically after a time.

Answer (score 3):

You just ignore it if you don't want to block them. You don't have to respond immediately to every email or even read them.

I have a folder I rarely look at which all emails I can't be bothered with get redirected into before they clutter my inbox.

Comment: "You don't have to respond immediately" is actually something I haven't considered yet. I replied to each email within minutes. Maybe delaying my responses could work, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score -3):

Just ask him what he wants in exchange for your peace. Ask him...I understand your "recommendations" but how can I help you with your purchase.